# Cocos2d handling touch multiple layers

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm trying to enable touch for layers as many other people have suggested online:

```
        hudLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addChild:hudLayer z:3];

        gameLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addChild:gameLayer z:1];
        gameLayer.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        rileyLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init]autorelease];
        [self addChild:rileyLayer z:2];

        pauseMenu = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addChild:pauseMenu z:4];

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:hudLayer priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

and my touchmethods are here:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(NSSet *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return  TRUE;
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(NSSet *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!paused) {
        ratMove = 0;
    }
}
```

however this continually throws the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layer#ccTouchBegan override me'

The only reason I could find for this error online is if you weren't including the ccTouchBegan function, however I am, does anyone else know any other reasons for this error to appear?

Comment: where are these thow method are? they must be in your hudLayer subclass

Comment: No the debugger tells me that, I haven't written any methods to throw that error, so they must be within cocos2d...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass CCLayer to have hud layer, then inside it implement these methods.

You add your hud layer as targeted delegate, then it must implement at least `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:` method. If you want your hud to be targeted delegate, make CCLayer subclass and implement there methods from targeted touch delegate protocol.

Comment: What? Don't really understand what you mean by that?

Comment: you even get exception message "ccTouchBegan#override me". what cannot you understand?

Comment: Ok now you've edited your answer it makes a lot more sense thank you! I'm fairly new to obj-c and to iOS programming! I will see which of the two answers suits me best and then answer :)

Comment: one big problem with this: I have to almost completely re-write my code, and also I can't access variables in gamelayer from the ccTouchEnded method if I put it in a Subclass of CCLayer... is there no way of doing it using my current method?

Comment: ok so this has (eventually got it working!) however I now need to access some variables that are variables of the scene rather than the subclass within the subclass, is that only possible with global variables?

Comment: you can do it with delegates. for example, make your scene a delegate of hud layer. then hud will be able to notify it's delegate about events(for example, about tap button fire or something else and so on)

Answer (score 0):

your function does not implement the appropriate signature. Try:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // your stuff here
}
```

if you want multiple touch handling (your signature), you should addStandardDelegate instead of targetedTouchDelegate.

EDIT : and now in objective-c:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addStandardDelegate:self priority:0];
```

There are two protocols implemented by the touch dispatcher. You are currently registering as a targetTouchDelegate but implementing the delegate methods of the standardDelegate. Use the line above to register if you want to keep your methods.

Edit 2 : and now the exact syntax of the protocols, straight from cocos's code. As you can see, no ccTouchBegan with NSSet (your signature) BUT INSTEAD ccTouchesBegan. Whichever handling method you prefer (targeted of standard), you must conform to the protocols below.

@protocol CCTargetedTouchDelegate

```
/** Return YES to claim the touch.
 @since v0.8
 */
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@optional
// touch updates:
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end

/**
 CCStandardTouchDelegate.

 This type of delegate is the same one used by CocoaTouch. You will receive all the  events (Began,Moved,Ended,Cancelled).
 @since v0.8
*/
@protocol CCStandardTouchDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end
```

Comment: argh ... you have a mix of syntax here in your code sample. see above edits.

Comment: this wasn't the reason for the problem I'm afraid, the reason was the fact I wasn't using ccTouchBegan within the layer subclass hudLayer :/

Comment: then you should also upvote Morion's answer when you accept it. How can it be the correct answer if it did not help you ?

Comment: it did help me, it was just a case of re-writing a large amount of code, so I was waiting to see if there was another way around it!